# Is this diagram, concerning Young's double slits, inaccurate?

Tags: optics, waves, double-slit-experiment, interference

"This diagram" :
[image]

My question is **whether those lines (interference) have to originate from a single point.**

The diagram used to demonstrate what $m$ (path difference) means, has two lines originating from the same point. 
[image]

**updated questions** Is it simply a coincidence or an inaccuracy of the diagram that the number of points of constructive interference, the line crosses, decreases by 1 from m=0, to m=3?

[image]

Comment: To answer your followup question: You seem to have missed a lot of crossings for $m=\pm 3$, so your pattern doesn't hold.

Comment: @JahanClaes, well you can't just look at the diagram. It's very likely inaccurate .

Comment: then what does a "crossing" mean exactly?

Comment: Like going though....

Answer (score 2):

The "lines" of constructive interference are not really "lines", although far away from the points they *approach* lines. What are they? They are "The set of points P where the distance from P to the top slit, minus the distance from P to the bottom slit, is a certain fixed value". And what is that set of points? You may have learned it in high-school math ... [It's a hyperbola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Difference_of_distances_to_foci)!

The "lines" are actually hyperbolas whose two "focal points" are the two slits. The hyperbolas have **asymptotes**: Lines that the hyperbola approaches far away from the foci. Those straight lines are what the textbook is drawing.

It is a mathematical fact that the asymptotes of a hyperbola pass through the point halfway between the two foci.

Therefore, to answer your question: The lines of constructive or destructive interference, if you extend them, should all meet at the point exactly halfway between the two slits.

[Note: OK, the m=0 curve actually is a straight line, it doesn't merely approach a straight line. A line is a special case of a hyperbola, in a certain sense. See ["degenerate hyperbola"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic).]

Comment: This is not answering my question

Comment: I added another couple paragraphs...